# Blink an div with jquery

Tags: jquery, blink

How can i blink a div. I have a hover on the div element. How can i make with jQuery. That the div is blink up and  blink down. And then on the 10 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: @Nick, yes. And then on the ten seconds.

Comment: What does blinking up and blinking down mean, could you give an existing example of what you want?

Comment: `<blink pattern="1111100000">up</blink> <blink pattern="0000011111">down</blink>`? (don't be serious on this)

Answer (score 9):

Is something like this what you are looking for?  This code will make the div appear and disappear every 10 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var blink = function(){
        $('#blinker').toggle();
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(blink, 10000);
    });
</script>

<div id="blinker">This will blink</div>
```

Comment: That'll make the `div` appear and disappear every **0.1** seconds, (`100` milliseconds). But otherwise, +1 =)

Comment: Oh, good catch.  I changed it to 100 when I was testing it. :)  Now it will go for 10 seconds.