# How to blink a div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blink an div with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060140/blink-an-div-with-jquery)

**I need to know how to make blink of div in jquery?**

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**html**

```
<div class="blink">blinking text</div>
```

**jquery**

```
function blink(selector){
$(selector).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        blink(this);
    });
});
}
    
blink('.blink');
```

**demo :**

```js
function blink(selector) {
  $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
      blink(this);
    });
  });
}

blink('.blink');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blink">blinking text</div>
non-blinking
<div class="blink">more blinking text</div>
```

---

**Update** (*bringing the answer up-to-date*)

You do not need to use jQuery for such effects anymore. You can do it with just CSS (*using [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)*).
(*compatibility table at http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation*)

**CSS** (*using the standard properties*)

```
.blink{
    animation:blink 700ms infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blink {
    from { opacity:1; }
    to { opacity:0; }
};
```

**Demo (with vendor prefixed properties) :**

```css
.blink {
  -webkit-animation: blink 700ms infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: blink 700ms infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: blink 700ms infinite alternate;
  animation: blink 700ms infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

;
```

```html
<div class="blink">blinking text</div>
non-blinking
<div class="blink">more blinking text</div>
```

Comment: If you wanted to just blink the Div backgroud-color and not the text how would you do that?

Comment: with css instead of animating the opacity animate the alpha channel using rgba. `from { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1); } to { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); }` (*for black*)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your div has `id="blinkMe"`

```
setInterval(function () {
   var vis = $("#blinkMe").css("visibility");
   vis = (!vis || vis == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
   $("#blinkMe").css("visibility", vis);
}, 500);
```

Note: used "visibility" and not "display" / `.toggle()` since the latter will cause layout to shift around while the div is blinking.